# Redirect from a subdomain route to root route

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 sets of routes, the domain is saved in the env file at `HOST`, the first group can be accesed by `example.com`, and the second should  be using `somesubdomain.example.com`, this work, the problem is when I whan to redirect from the `subdomains route` to the `root routes`, the `subdomain` persist so the `root route` won't enter, I have tried using `named routes` but it redirects to `localhost/dashboard` that is xampp dashboard.

```
//root routes
Route::namespace('Main')->domain(env('HOST'))->group(function(){
    Route::get('/','Home\HomeController@getMain')->name('inicio');//i have tried to name the route but this just redirect to localhost/dashboard
});
//subdomain routes
Route::namespace('Stores')->domain('{subdomain}.'.env('HOST'))->group(function(){
    Route::get('/',function(){
        return redirect()->route('inicio');
    });
});
```

both routes work, if instead of `redirect` I do `return 'foo';` it shows foo when it has the subdomain, and return a view when it doesn't.

how can I remove the subdomain and redirect to the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution might be to redirect to the named route without any parameters and without an absolute URL, for example:

```
//root routes
Route::namespace('Main')->domain(env('HOST'))->group(function(){
    Route::get('/','Home\HomeController@getMain')->name('inicio');
});
//subdomain routes
Route::namespace('Stores')->domain('{subdomain}.'.env('HOST'))->group(function(){
    Route::get('/',function(){
        return redirect()->to(route('inicio', [], false);
    });
});
```

The only change being the redirect which should look something like:

```
return redirect()->to(route('inicio', [], false);
```

The first parameter being the named route, the second includes any parameters (in this case none) and the third specifies if the URL should be absolute.

I don't have an environment on hand to test this, but hopefully, it is a solution that will work for you.